# error while loading csv file though snlowsql copy into command

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i was trying to load csv file from AWS s3 bucket with copy into command in one of the csv file throw error like

> End of record reached while expected to parse column
> '"RAW_PRODUCTS"["PACK_COUNT_UNITS":25]

and with the VALIDATION_MODE = RETURN_ALL_ERRORS it also give me 2 rows that have error i am not sure what error would be.
my concern is can we get specific error so that we can fix it in file.

Comment: Perhaps there is some unicode characters, carriage return etc in the data that may be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

You might try using the VALIDATE table function. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/validate.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Eda, i already reviewed above link but that did not work with sql query with copy into table from s3 bucket, so i create stage and place that csv file on stage and then try to run that validate command that give me same error row.
there is another way to identify error while executing copy into command you can add `VALIDATION_MODE = RETURN_ALL_ERRORS` you will get same result.

by the way i resolve error its due to `/,,` i remove / and it loaded successfully. `/` or `/,` is working as it was in other row but `/,,` did not work.